# How to run mvn verify in a maven-download disabled box?

Tags: java, maven

I need to run `mvn verify` in a secured box where maven is not able to download anything. I am able to run the command on my local laptop, so I copied my local .m2 folder to the secured box. However, I got this error:

```
$ mvn verify -o
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <Masked strings>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.109s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 07 20:49:26 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:19 is not available in the local repository. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

So, looks like copying `.m2` is not enough. So, what should I do to make sure maven can do the job without downloading anything?

Thank you very much.

Comment: was the mvn verify successful on your local laptop ?

Comment: please check if the repository-folder inside ```.m2``` contains the folder ```org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19```.

Comment: -@JigarJoshi: Yes, the `mvn verify` was successful on my laptop.

Comment: -@lefloh: Yes, the copied `.m2` contains that. In fact, it contains everything from my local `.m2`.

Comment: check your maven settings for the repository url as well. mvn help:effective-settings